# Notice: session_start(): Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active in

Tags: php, seguridad

tengo una página donde manejo 3 tipos de usuario:
Administrador, organizador y usuario
El loggin hace las validaciones correspondientes y de acuerdo al tipo de usuario cuentan con diferentes permisos, por ejemplo, el administrador puede eliminar y dar de alta "membresias".

El problema es que si escribo la URL directamente en el navegador http://localhost/Mi-pagina/membresias.php (esta) entra por defecto a la página del administrador lo que permitiría que cualquiera agregue o elimine membresias.

Intenté con

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
```

pero no me funciona ya que me manda el error de que la sesión ya esta iniciada

> Notice: session_start(): Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mi-pagina\menu2.php on line 2

Para generar el menú lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
session_start();
?>

  <ul>
       <li class="submenu"><a href="perfil.php">Mi perfil</a></li>
       <li><a href="membresias.php">Membresias</a></li>
       <?php if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario']==1) { ?>
       <li><a href='administrar.php'>Administrar</a></li>
       <?php } ?>
       <li><a href="salir.php">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Este menú lo incluí en todas las páginas:

```
<?php include 'menu2.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Hay un session_start() en conexion.php ?

Comment: No, la sesión esta iniciada en "menu2.php" y ese archivo esta incluido en "membresias.php"

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de resolver esto. La forma más **simple y básica**, es colocando condicionales para evaluar si la sesión está activa y así mostrar la página. En PHP puro, debes indicarle a cada página como quieres que esta responda.

El siguiente código es una plantilla de ejemplo que te puede servir para aplicar el concepto en tu desarrollo.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'header.php'; // Header HTML, include CSS, Menu superior, etc

function escribir_bd() {
    $name = $_POST['nombre_var'];
    // ... etc
    // Instrucciones SQL
}

function mostrar_pagina() {
    ?>
    <div id="main_id" class="mainclass">
        <!-- Contenido de la pagina -->
    </div>
    <?php
}

if(isset($_POST['nombre_var'])) {
    escribir_bd();
}

// #### Validaciones ####
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario_id'])) {
    if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == 2) { // Suponiendo que 2 sea algún privilegio
        mostrar_pagina();
    } else {
        echo 'Este usuario no tiene privilegios para ver esta pagina';
        echo '[[ link para volver al Home ]]';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Para acceder aqui debes iniciar sesión';
    echo '[[ link para iniciar sesion ]]';
}

require_once 'footer.php'; // Cierre HTML
```

La parte de `if(isset($_POST['nombre_var']))` es por si tienes algún formulario que quieres que se actualice en la misma página. Si se presiona un botón `submit`, encontrará ese `if` antes de las validaciones, por lo que se llamará la función `escribir_bd()`, se actualizará el registro, y una vez que termina se continúa con la carga de la página, la cual traerá los nuevos datos actualizados.